# Why wont the onroomconnected switch scenes in unity when its called by google play services

Tags: unity-game-engine

So Ive been following this tutorial for implementing real time multiplayer with google play services for unity [Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/86040/creating-cross-platform-multiplayer-game-unity-part-1). However I got stuck on part two whenever I test it between two devices I happen to use android. It wont move to the game scene It just hangs out in the main menu. I have not used adb but I have been able to invite people.

```
    public void OnRoomConnected(bool success)
{
    if (success)
    {
        ShowMpStatus("We are connected");

        lobbyListener = null;
        SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
    } else
    {
        ShowMpStatus("Sorry not connected");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this to load and send you to the next scene. 
SceneManager.LoadScene ("OtherSceneName", LoadSceneMode.Single);

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.LoadSceneMode.html

Comment: I'm sorry it randomly worked It just takes a second or two and I'm impatient